# jQuery hasAttr checking to see if there is an attribute on an element

Tags: jquery

How do you check if there is an attribute on an element in jQuery? Similar to `hasClass`, but with `attr`?

For example,

```
if ($(this).hasAttr("name")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: quickie: `if(  $(this).is('[ATTRIBUTE_NAME]')  ) { /* ... */ }` **BTW:** this is not a duplicate of that question anymore, is just a similar question regarding different problem, the linked duplicate is now called "Select elements by attribute"

Comment: jQuery has no .hasAttr() function, but it is easy to implement:                 jQuery.prototype.hasAttr = function(attribute) {
    var a = $(this).attr(attribute);
    return ((typeof a !== "undefined") && (a !== false));
};

Answer (score 1260, accepted):

```
var attr = $(this).attr('name');

// For some browsers, `attr` is undefined; for others,
// `attr` is false.  Check for both.
if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @FuzzyDunlop, Yes, but if `attr` is `""` that would return `false` as well.  It should be `true`, because an empty attribute is a valid attribute.  Also, there's no need for a double-not because `if` casts it down to bool anyway.

Comment: I think we use `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: @Pyjcoder In this case the use of `&&` is correct. If the attribute is not undefined AND not false it should continue in the `if` statement. If either condition ends up false it should skip over the `if`. In the case where you invert the code (possibly for returning or error handling) you would need to use `||` since you would want to catch only if either condition is matched

Answer (score 711):

How about just `$(this).is("[name]")`?

The `[attr]` syntax is the CSS selector for an element with an attribute `attr`, and `.is()` checks if the element it is called on matches the given CSS selector.

Comment: How about speed comparison for this method and `.attr`?

Answer (score 163):

If you will be checking the existence of attributes frequently, I would suggest creating a `hasAttr` function, to use as you hypothesized in your question:

```
$.fn.hasAttr = function(name) {  
   return this.attr(name) !== undefined;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.edit').hasAttr('id')) {
        alert('true');
    } else {
        alert('false');
    }
});

<div class="edit" id="div_1">Test field</div>
```

Answer (score 128):

You're so close it's crazy.

```
if($(this).attr("name"))
```

There's no hasAttr but hitting an attribute by name will just return undefined if it doesn't exist.

This is why the below works. If you remove the name attribute from #heading the second alert will fire.

**Update:** As per the comments, the below will **ONLY** work if the attribute is present **AND** is set to something not if the attribute is there but empty

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if ($("#heading").attr("name"))
      alert('Look, this is showing because it\'s not undefined');
    else
      alert('This would be called if it were undefined or is there but empty');
});
</script>
<h1 id="heading" name="bob">Welcome!</h1>
```

Comment: if the name attr is present but empty string, the attribute would exist but the test would fail.

Answer (score 98):

Late to the party, but... why not just `this.hasAttribute("name")`?

Refer [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute)

Comment: or if you don't care that it won't work in a lot of older browsers and IE

Comment: Btw, these days hasAttribute is totally safe to use https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_hasattribute

Answer (score 23):

The best way to do this would be with `filter()`:

```
$("nav>ul>li>a").filter("[data-page-id]");
```

It would still be nice to have .hasAttr(), but as it doesn't exist there is this way.

Answer (score 7):

```
Object.prototype.hasAttr = function(attr) {
    if(this.attr) {
        var _attr = this.attr(attr);
    } else {
        var _attr = this.getAttribute(attr);
    }
    return (typeof _attr !== "undefined" && _attr !== false && _attr !== null);      
};
```

I came a crossed this while writing my own function to do the same thing... I though I'd share in case someone else stumbles here. 
I added null because getAttribute() will return null if the attribute does not exist.

This method will allow you to check jQuery objects and regular javascript objects.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use it with attributes such as disabled="disabled" on the form fields etc. like so:

```
$("#change_password").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr("rel");
    if($("#" + target).attr("disabled")) {
        $("#" + target).attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $("#" + target).attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

The "rel" attribute stores the id of the target input field.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a hasAttr() plugin for jquery that will do all of this very simply, exactly as the OP has requested. More information [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hasAttr)

**EDIT:**
My plugin was deleted in the great plugins.jquery.com database deletion disaster of 2010. You can look [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hasattr) for some info on adding it yourself, and why it hasn't been added.

Comment: Funny that those links don't work in IE 8, but do in Chrome...