# jquery hasAttr in Webkit and Opera

Tags: jquery, attributes

Aloha,

I found an answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element). Basically i'm looking to tell if a tag has an attribute. I don't care what the value is, just if there is one.

I'm currently using:

```
$.fn.hasAttr = function (attr) {
    var attribVal = this.attr(attr);
    alert(attr+" ["+attribVal+"]");
    return (attribVal !== undefined) && (attribVal !== false);
};
```

This function is not working in Opera or Webkit. It returns true even if the attribute does not exist. The alert that I added shows that the `attribVal` is equal to blank, not false, not undefined, not null, but blank. Firefox and IE this works fine in as `attribVal` is undefined.

The problem is I want it to return true for a blank attribute, if its on the tag and false for no attribute on the tag.

**Edit:** 
expected results...

```
<tag />                    should be hasAttr('placeholder') = false
<tag placeholder />        should be hasAttr('placeholder') = true
<tag placeholder="" />     should be hasAttr('placeholder') = true
<tag placeholder="Hi" />   should be hasAttr('placeholder') = true
```

**Edit:** Current code

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/4UJJk/1/) works in WebKit and FF, not in IE or Opera.

**Update**  After all this, my original code works, unless I am looking at the placeholder attribute. Opera and webkit return true for all four options when I'm looking at the placeholder attribute. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4UJJk/3/) for an example. I've updated my expected results to use the placeholder attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in all browsers:

```
 $.fn.hasAttr = function (attr) {
     for (var i = 0; i < this[0].attributes.length; i++) {
         if (this[0].attributes[i].nodeName == attr) {return true}
     }
    return false;
 };
```

Comment: This worked in all the browsers i could test - IE(7/8), FF (Win/Mac), Opera (Win/Mac), Chrome (Win/Mac), Safari (Win/Mac)  http://jsfiddle.net/4UJJk/12/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't check explicitly against `undefined`, but just check for `falsy values`.

```
return !!attribVal;
```

That will return `false` for `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `NaN`, `0` and of course `false`.

[Read more about `!!`.](http://typeofnan.blogspot.com/2010/11/about-javascript-shortcuts-trickery.html)

**Update**

Your desired behavior should be possible invoking Sizzle:

```
$.fn.hasAttr = function (attr) {
    var attribVal = this.attr(attr);
    return (typeof attribVal === 'string');
};
```

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/4UJJk/11/

Comment: I've added what my expected results should be. !!attribVal would return false for the middle two, when is should not.

Comment: See my test: http://jsfiddle.net/4UJJk/1/  This works in webkit and Firefox, not IE or Opera

Comment: @Justin808: doh, can't test on one either currently.

Comment: The results for both are false, false, false, true

Comment: @Justin808: I finally could test it on IE - see my update, that should do it crossbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, jQuery-ish solution would be:

```
$.fn.hasAttr = function(attr) {
    return this.is('[' + attr + ']');
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4UJJk/9/).  NB I haven't got access to IE or Opera right now to test this...