# IE 8 option selected attribute not rendered in AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, html-select

When I load html content using AJAX that includes a selected option, it is not rendered on the client.

For example

```
<option selected='selected'>text</option>
```

Now if I use

```
$("option [selected]")
```

I get empty result, but it works well in FireFox. I checked source code using Develper Tools and selected is not in the html content. That's weird!

Comment: It should be `<option selected="selected">text</option>` with double quotes

Comment: try without space `$("option[selected]")`

Comment: I think it must be `$("select option:selected")`

Comment: I tried with "", $("option[selected]") but it does not work. 
$("select option:selected") behaves differently. When there is an item selected it works fine, but if no option is selected it just returns the first option which is not correct.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what are you final goal. Knowing if some option is selected or if it has the selected attribute.

Comment: I have to loop through all options to test each one for .attr("selected"). It shouldn't be like that because i am using a jQuery plugin that already uses jQuery [] syntax. Now whose bug is this? IE? or jQuery?
using Developer tools in IE I couldn't see the "selected" attribute rendered Can any of you check on their side?

Comment: Here is a test case:
http://jsfiddle.net/kR2ks/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, and I think this is an IE8 issue, as it seems to work in IE7...

Have run some tests and I suggest that you try a conditional statement in jQuery and use the square brackets with anything else but IE, and for IE use the colon version:

non IE:
$("option[selected]");

IE:
$("option:selected");

PS. to be more clear, you can use the colon version for everything but FireFox 3, so FF4 and WebKit will also work with the colon version. Haven't done a multi version thorough test, just assume latest as of this date. So I guess it's up to you if you want to do a conditional based on IE or FF 3...