# jQuery how to check if attribute exists before removing it

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, attributes

I am getting an error `object property doesn't support this method` when I try to remove the attribute when I load the page.

However I believe this is happening because the disabled attribute was never added on page load, because I do not receive the error after the attribute is added.

My question is how can I check if the attribute exists before trying to remove it.

Thanks

```
 if (jQuery.inArray($("select option:selected").val(), Codes) == -1) {
                $(serviceSelector).hide();
                $(LocationSelector).hide();

                $("#ctl00_ctl00_body_body_ddlPool option['value=ADD']").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#ctl00_ctl00_body_body_ddlPool option['value=ADM']").removeAttr("disabled");
            } else {
                $(serviceSelector).show();
                $(LocationSelector).show();
                $("#ctl00_ctl00_body_body_ddlPool  option[value=ADM]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#ctl00_ctl00_body_body_ddlPool  option[value=ADD]").attr("disabled", "disabled");

            }
            //$find(AcId).set_contextKey($(this).val());
        }).change();
```

Comment: Please see this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element

Comment: You have syntax errors in your selectors: `option['value=ADD']` should be `option[value='ADD']` (and similarly for other `[name='value']` selectors).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `.hasAttribute` method

If you have more than one of each ADD and ADM nodes you will have to test each one:

```
$("#ctl00_ctl00_body_body_ddlPool option[value='ADD']").each(function(){
    if(this.hasAttribute("disabled"))
        this.removeAttribute("disabled");
});
```

Otherwise just test against the actual node

```
if($("#ctl00_ctl00_body_body_ddlPool option[value='ADD']")[0].hasAttribute("disabled"))
```

EDIT: fixed syntax error per Andrew's comment.

Comment: He's right - Also, it's really helpful to use a debugging console like [firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) or [developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html#access). The console is your friend.