# how can I check to see if my <select> element contains the multiple attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi I have tried many options to check if the multiple attribute is set in my select box but none have worked. I am trying to determine if the current select box that I am getting values from is a multiple select so far this is what I have tried:

```
if($(":select[multiple]").length){
           alert("worked");
}
```

also

```
if($("select").attr("multiple"){
           alert("worked");
}
```

also

```
if($("select").attr("multiple") != 'undefined'{
           alert("worked");
}
```

html:

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="height:50px" class="classname" name="multi_values[]"> 
 <option value="blah">blah</option> 
 <option value="blah">blah</option> 
 <option value="blah">blah</option>              
</select>
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element

Comment: tried that and it is not working skips to my "else statement"

Comment: Have posted an answer.. Check it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove `:` at the beginning of :

```
if($("select[multiple]").length){
    alert("worked");
}
```

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/D5JX5/

Comment: that worked but it worked for all select boxes not just the ones with the multiple attribute in them

Answer (score 3):

Also simple javascript check:

```js
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('select'); //collection
for (var i=0, l = c.length; i<l; i++) {
    alert(typeof c[i].attributes['multiple'] == 'undefined' ? 'single':'multiple');
}
```

And jQuery equivalent:

```
$('select').each(function(){
  alert( typeof this.attributes['multiple'] == 'undefined' ? 'single':'multiple' );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All the options except `":select[multiple]"` (shd be `"select[multiple]"`) you tried should work.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VAXF6/2/

However you are missing a closing paran for your if statement.

Change your code to:

```
if($("select[multiple]").length){
           alert("worked");
}
```

or

```
if($("select").attr("multiple")){
           alert("worked");
}
```

or

```
if($("select").attr("multiple") != 'undefined'){
           alert("worked");
}
```

Another alternative:

```
if($("select").is("[multiple]")){
           alert("worked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to only alert if multiple was set with a value, not just if it exists as an attribute:

```
if($("select[multiple='multiple']").length){
    alert("worked"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using one of the following boolean indicators that has not been proposed: 
`let selects =  document.getElementsByName('multi_values[]'); // returns collection`
Method 1 : [hasAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute)

```
for (let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    const select = selects[i];
    if (select.hasAttribute('multiple')) {
        alert('Multiple select found');
        break;
    }
}
```

Method 2 : [bang bang](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#double_not_!!) [Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes#basic_examples)

```
for (let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    const select = selects[i];
    if (!!select.attributes['multiple']) {
        alert('Multiple select found');
        break;
    }
}
```