# placeholder plugin for tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I'm looking for a plugin or implementation to include HTML5-like `placeholder` text in a tinymce editor but without success. Do you how if it exist? Or How can I implement this functionality?

Exactly how I can do with Ckeditor:

http://alfonsoml.blogspot.it/2012/04/placeholder-text-in-ckeditor.html

Comment: Can you describe what function a _placeholder plugin_ performs?

Comment: like this: http://alfonsoml.blogspot.it/2012/04/placeholder-text-in-ckeditor.html. I would want that a simple text "insert something here" appear by default if editor content is empty and if user get focus on editor it must be disappear. If user loose focus on editor and content is empty, the default text must be reset

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tinymce html5 placeholder by reading attribute from textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693989/tinymce-html5-placeholder-by-reading-attribute-from-textarea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is answered in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693989/tinymce-html5-placeholder-by-reading-attribute-from-textarea) and should work for you too.