# how to make $(":text[placeholder]" to work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

My code contains these lines  :

```
 $(":text[placeholder], :password[placeholder]").each(function(){
    //some code
  });
```

It is working fine on chrome and ff but getting the below error in IE8 .

```
 Object doesn't support this property or method
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I guess you're not using that quotation in your code ? It wouldn't work anywhere around.

Comment: @adeneo: IE10 doesn't support `placeholder` and `required` attributes ?

Comment: have you tried this: `$('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]')`

Comment: Don't use `:text`,`:password`. They are [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)!! Use `input[type="text"][placeholder]`, etc...instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can try this:

```
$("input[type='text'], input[type='password']").filter(function(){
    var attr = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    return typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false;
}).each(function(){
    //some code
});
```

<sub>Attribute's checking code borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318091/1113426)</sub>