# How can I detect if a label has a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown menu that contains checkboxes, and more than one can be checked at once. When a checkbox is selected, it's label's class is set to "checked" and then removed when it is deselected.

Before checkbox is selected:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="gainlosstypes[]" value="Losses" class="upperFilter">Losses</label>
```

After checkbox is selected:

```
<label class="checked"><input type="checkbox" name="gainlosstypes[]" value="Losses" class="upperFilte">Losses</label>
```

When it is selected the label element has `.toggleClass('checked')` called on it.

I need to be able to detect which label's have their class set to "checked" so that I can filter data based on those fields.

If `$(this)` is the label element, when I try `$(this).hasClass('checked')` it throws an error. That's the only way I know to try. Is there some other way to tell if a specific label element has a specific class?

**Edit:**

I get these errors when trying to check for the attribute. It also happens when I use hasClass:

```
> $(".multiSelectOptions :checkbox")[1].attr('checked')
TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'attr'
> $(".multiSelectOptions :checkbox").parent('label')[1].attr('checked')
TypeError: Object #<HTMLLabelElement> has no method 'attr'
```

Comment: This should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element

You can do `$('').attr('checked')`

Comment: Show some code - are you setting an actual class on the label, or are you confusing `class` and `attribute`? A checkbox can have a `checked` _attribute_

Comment: create a fiddle please

Comment: what error ?Please post console log

Comment: Why do you use label with checkboxs? would it make more sense to use `<select multiple><options value='yourvaluehere'>Your label text here</option><select>` ????

Comment: I can understand not wanting to use `<select>` and `<option>` so that you can use custom styles on your drop downs.

Comment: Concerning your edit.  Is `$(".multiSelectOptions :checkbox")` getting any results?

Comment: @ErikChristianson Yes. It returns all of my checkboxes.

Comment: Why not use just plain JQuery selector?? $('.checked') would work great ??

Comment: The problem is your use of `[1]` before `.attr()` or `.hasClass()`. That extracts the DOM element from the jQuery object, but these methods only operate on jQuery objects.

Comment: @Sebastien He wants to test if a specific element `$(this)` has the class, not find all the elements with the class.

Comment: Yes but in the question he is not using $(this) anymore.

Comment: Could you post your JQuery code?? that would help

Comment: And hasClass should work. I am starting to think the error might be somewhere else than at the .hasclass

Comment: Was'nt crazy after all I knew plain selector would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked is not a css class it is an html attribute. thus you should check for the attribute not the class.

You should try :

```
if($(this).attr('checked') != null)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

EDIT:

Like @Bojangles said `checked` could be a custom CSS class but it would probably make more sense to check for checked checkbox with the attribute rather than a custom css class.

EDIT #2:

PLEASE SKIP PREVIOUS ANSWER AND USE THIS INSTEAD:

You could use the JQuery selector on this:

For exemple:

```
$('.checked')//this would get you all the element with the class 'checked'

//if you want to check if you have any check element:

if($('.checked').length > 0)
{
    //do stuff here
}

//To loop trought all the element that are 'checked'

$('.checked').each(
function(index)
{
    $(this).removeClass('checked');
    //do stuff here for exemple...
}
)
```

Comment: Ah yes, but it _can be_ a CSS class, hence everyone's confusion

Comment: @Bojangles You are right it could be a CSS class but from what I saw in the question it look like the attribute not a custom CSS class.

Answer (score -2):

This will set checked if the label has the attribute 'checked' set, otherwise you'll get undefined and can base your logic off this.

```
var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
```

Comment: `var theSolutionYoureLookingFor = unExplainedFunction()`

Comment: Answers should contain **explanations**, not just a single line of code

Answer (score -2):

How about

```
if( $(this).attr('class') == "checked" ){
    ... do something
}
```

That will check for the class of checked . . .