# Why FormData post disabled html fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data, disabled-input

I'm using jquery `$.ajax();` function to post data of a form,
to get the data of the form i'm using `new FormData` because in my form there is an input file too.

The problem is i've disabled fields too in my form, those normally are not posted, but if i use new `FormData` they are.

How to solve this problem? I don't need to post disabled input fields!

Comment: why are u using `new` keyword, besides that after using the new keyword, you can code to disable the fields again, dnt it will work

Comment: Question No. 1 is do you need those disabled fields? Question number two, since input fields are added to FormData object by append method - arent you adding those disabled fields to your FormData object?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post to show us the code you're using?

Answer (score 2):

How about building the `FormData` with only the fields you want:

```
// New FormData, get form and inputs
var payload = new FormData(),
    $form = $("form")
    $inputs = $("input", $form);

// For each input
for (var i = 0, l = $inputs.length; i < l; i++) {
    // Cache jQuery selector for input and get disabled attr
    var $input = $(inputs[i]),
        disabled_attr = $input.attr("disabled");

    // If the disabled attr is undefined or false
    // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element
    if (disabled_attr === "undefined" || disabled_attr === false) {

        // Append the key value pair to the FormData
        payload.append($input.attr("name"), $input.attr("value"));
    }
}
```

You should now be able to submit the FormData using `data` on `$.ajax`.  If this fails, you can submit it using vanilla JavaScript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.send(payload);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about new FormData, but here is an alternative solution. If your form doesn't contain too many fields, use **data** property of $.ajax() call and send the required fields and their values only to the server. Sample syntax will be like as following

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST" OR "GET",
url: "/someUrl",
data: 
{
  'id' : $('#empId').val(),
  'name' : $('$empName').val()
} ,
dataType: "json",
success: function(result){
    alert(result);
}});
```

Comment: OP said his form does contain `<input type=image>`s, with which your method does not work. This question *is* about `Formdata`…

Comment: Then we can use "multipart/form-data" technique to send data. Please refer to the posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax for more info

Comment: @Makesh: Yes, that's exactly what the OP did but with which he had problems.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is i've disabled fields too in my form, those normally are not posted, but if i use `new FormData` they are.

According to the [XHR](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#interface-formdata) and [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#constructing-form-data-set), they indeed must not be serialized. You should submit a bug against those browsers who do.

> How to solve this problem? I don't need to post disabled input fields!

I you just don't need them, wait for a fix. If you require them to be omitted, you could try the following workaround:

```
var $form = /* whatever you have */;
var $inputs = $form.find(":disabled").each(function() {
    $(this).data("xhr-name", this.name);
    this.name = ""; // fields with empty names must be ignored as well
});
var formdata = new FormData($form[0]);
$inputs.each(function() {
    this.name = $(this).data("xhr-name");
});
```

If this neither works, you could a) completely detach the inputs from the DOM and restore them later, or b) construct the `FormData` manually.