# Accessing attributes and properties in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a existing application which uses javascript and properties like notNull, isDate etc defined within the elements in html elements like input, select, etc

For example:

```
<input type = 'text' notNull class='mandatoryField' name = 'abc' id='abc' isDate/>
```

And the javascript checks for the properties with a hasProp method, placing the code below and corresponding warning messages are displayed:

```
function hasProp(thisField, thisProp) {
for ( var prop in thisField) {
    if (prop == thisProp)
        return true;
}
return false;
}
```

My issue here is with using different browsers - IE, Chrome and Firefox

This particular methods are all ok for Internet Explorer. when it comes to chrome and firefox, the notNull, isDate are treated as attributes rather than properties and the above hasProp method always returns false.

I did go through many questions available here, but couldn't find any way to access both properties and attributes in a single way - I would prefer jQuery to be used, since we will be migrating to jQuery eventually.

Any pointers to this will be really helpful.

Thanks,
Reema

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery hasAttr checking to see if there is an attribute on an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element)

Comment: How can this be a duplicate? I want a way to access property as well as method in a single for loop or statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you use the *attribute* and *property* aren't 100% accurate, properties (`.prop()`) in the jQuery context are basically the value of the attribute in memory, where as `.attr()` reflects the value in the markup. This is only the case for HTML attributes that are "built-in".
So in your example, you're dealing with attributes all the way, just some don't happen to have any value.

The best way of detecting the presence of an attribute, cross browser using jQuery:

```
$('#myElement').is('[attrName]') === true
```

So, in your case:

```
$('#abc').is('[isDate]') === true
```

See [this JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nhe8E/4/)

Answer (score 0):

As you want a jQuery solution, you can use both jQuery.attr() and jQuery.prop() methods to solve your problem.

Comment: There is no `.hasProp()` :)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer an pure Javascript approach:

```
var attributes = ['notNull', 'isDate'],
    checkForAttribute = function(elem){
      for(var i = 0, c = attributes.length ; i < c ; i++){
        if(elem.getAttribute(attributes[i]) !== null){
          console.log("attribute " + attributes[i] + " found");
        }else{
          console.log("attribute " + attributes[i] + " not found");
        }
      }
    }
```

See an **[working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xIwYEoXgkhiN15lW4Dxz)**.

[Here is some more information on the getAttribute() method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)

Comment: This would check only for the attributes and not properties. I need to check if i have notNull as either a property or an attribute.

Comment: You can expand the function. If the element has the attribute notNull and the attribute has also an values than you could return it.