# jQuery add class to object containing one string but not another

Tags: jquery

I'm not understanding something here. This gives an error "undefined is not a function" for line 5. I want to add a class to every link that has ".mp3" but does not have ".php".

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a[href$=".mp3"]')
    .each(function()
    { 
        if (this.toString().indexOf(".php")<0) { $(this).addClass('sm2_button');}
    });
    var btn = jQuery('<span class="btn-pressplay">&nbsp;</span>');
    jQuery('.sm2_button').prepend(btn)
});`

Edit:
I also tried the following per @user3659034. The error I get is Type error: undefined is not a function
console.log produces "a#page-top" so looks like I'm trying to evaluate a weird a on my page that I need to exclude. I got the typeof code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element).

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //edit NEB
    //jQuery('a[href$=".mp3"]').addClass('sm2_button');
    jQuery("a").each(function(idx) {
        console.log (this);
        var attr = $(this).attr('href');
        if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
        if (jQuery(this).attr('href').indexOf(".mp3")  >  -1) {
            if (jQuery(this).attr('href').indexOf(".php")  ==  -1) {
                 jQuery(this).addClass('sm2_button');
            }
        }
        }
    });
    var btn = jQuery('<span class="btn-pressplay">&nbsp;</span>');
    jQuery('.sm2_button').prepend(btn)
});`
This is for the pressplay-lite wordpress plugin to limit changing mp3 links that are downloads instead of mp3s.

Comment: can you share a sample

Comment: @Arun P Johny Sure-- I edited above.

Comment: try `jQuery('a[href$=".mp3"]').not('[href*=".php"]').addClass('sm2_button');`

Comment: @Arun P Johny Yes! I thought there must be a way to do it like that. Didn't understand the href$ and still not sure what it means but that did it. I'd accept your answer if it was under answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to use attribute selectors to say select elements with href ending with `.mp3`([attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) - $=) but ignore items having `.php` in the href attribute([attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) - *=) like

```
jQuery('a[href$=".mp3"]').not('[href*=".php"]').addClass('sm2_button');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery .each()` for anchor tag `a` and get it `href attribute's` value then check either exist .php or .mp3 in there.

```
$("a").each(function(idx) {
    if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf(".mp3")  >  -1) {
        $(this).addClass('sm2_button');
    }
});
```