# How to Check if other page field value is empty using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

I'm getting **all contacts** from Mysql db and then showing it on html row.  Each row has `onClick()` method After click on each **row** it will show a **details of contact** to the right side of **all contacts**.

**showing All contacts:**

```
echo "<tr onclick='getDetails($cdid), showthirdbox($cdid), visited(this);'>";                               
echo "<td class='' valign='top' align='left' width='20'>$companyName</td>";
echo "<td class='' valign='top'>$family_name</td>";
echo "<td class='' valign='top'>$given_name</td>";
echo "<td class='' valign='top'>$department</td>";
echo "<td class='' valign='top'>$title</td>";    
echo "</tr>";
```

This `getDetails()` call the `getContactDetails.php` (Contact Details) page. In this page I've a field called `Note` where user can enter notes.

So now I want to show a **Confirm message** to the user Only if user write something on `Enter Note` box but click other **row** (all contacts) without save this `Enter Notes`

Confirm mesaage will be : Do you want to save this Notes box before you go to other Contact ? Yes Or No. If Yes then `saveNote()` will be call otherwise it will load the new contact row.

I've no idea how can I do this using Jquery or Javascript ? Do you have any idea or solution ? Thank you.

**getDetails() function:**

```
function getDetails(id) {
            id = id;
            $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"getContactDetails.php",
            data:"id="+id,
            success:function(res){
                $('#visiable').show();
                $('#notebox_visiable').show();
                $('#thirdBox').show();

                $('#all_contact_details').html(res);
                showthirdbox(id);
                //showNotexBox(id);
                //showAllNotesBox(id);
                }
           });
}
```

**getContactDetails.php page have `Note` field:**

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">Enter Note<p id="demo"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">        
    <center><img id="loading-image" src="images/loading-image.gif" style="display:none; margin-bottom:10px !important;"/></center>
    <div id="Notesboxsuccess"></div>
    <form action="" method="post" id="showNotesBox" name="notebox">      
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="cdid" id="cdid"/>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><textarea name="contentText" id="contentText"  cols="35" rows="4" placeholder="enter note"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" class="submit" id="addNewNotes"/></td>
</tr>
    </form>
```

**Home page view after click on a row (All contacts) :**

[image]

Comment: You could do this: add an `onchange` handler to the note box. In that handler, set an custom attribute to the text field, something like `$(notebox).attr('change','yes')`. Then in the `onclick` of your contact list, before you change anything, check if the notebox has an attribute `change=yes` and display your messge.

Comment: @Michel Thanks for your response. Can you show me how exactly to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`change` only triggers on blur, so as long as the user stays in the textbox there is nothing to do.

[jQuery change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Attach a change event handler:

```
$("#contentText").change(function() {
    $("#contentText").attr("ididwritesomething","yep");
    }
```

In the save button remove the attribute [jQuery removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/)

```
$("#contentText").removeAttr("ididwritesomething");
```

In the click handler for your contact list, check if the attribute is set [(from this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318091/1685196):

```
var attr = $("#contentText").attr("ididwritesomething");
if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false && attr=="yep"){
       //do you want to save?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use [jQuery Change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function to do this.
For example,

```html
<input id="field" type="text" value="abcd">
<a id="pid" href="#">Link</a>
```

For the above html code the jQuery code is following

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pid").click(function(){
  $("#field").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
  });// end of change
});// end of click function
});//end of document
```