# check if an element has data attribute attached to it?

Tags: jquery

How can i check for  a custom data attribute attached to an element?
Here is my code.
how to see if the `img` has any data-* attached to it?

```
<img id="myImg" src="#" data-tablet="img/xl.jpg"   data-desktop="img/xl.jpg">
```

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery hasAttr checking to see if there is an attribute on an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
if($('img').is('[data-tablet]'))
```

Or if you want to just want to check if there is a `data-*`, you can do it this way by searching on the outerHTML of the element which you get either by using `get` or using an indexer.

```
if($('img')[0].outerHTML.indexOf("data-") > -1)
```

Comment: i mean to check if my image has just about any data attached to it.

Comment: can you tell me what does the second code mean.I mean can you explain it.Thanks.

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini that takes the html structure of the img and then searches if there is any "data-" string in the string and returns true if it is present else false

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini outerHTML returns whole structure for given element, not only attributes - so for example if your image src or name will contain "data-", this code will also return true.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over the attributes while checking the string for "data-"

```
var el = document.getElementById("myImg");
for (var i = 0; i < el.attributes.length; i++){
   // string comparison on 'data' with : el.attributes[i] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkCustomData(objectId){

    var attributes = document.getElementById(objectId).attributes;
    var customDataStatus = false;

    for (var x=0; x<attributes.length ; x++ ) {

        if (attributes[x].name.indexOf("data-") == 0) var customDataStatus = true;

    }

    return customDataStatus

}


console.log(checkCustomData("myImg"))
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pyqd1fLg/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.fn._hasData = function() {
  return [].some.call(this[0].attributes, function(v, k) {
    return /^data-/.test(v["name"])
  })
};
console.log($("img")._hasData())
```

```js
$.fn._hasData = function() {
  return [].some.call(this[0].attributes, function(v, k) {
    return /^data-/.test(v["name"])
  })
};
console.log($("img")._hasData())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="myImg" src="#" data-tablet="img/xl.jpg"   data-desktop="img/xl.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys
`Object.keys(document.getElementById('myImg').dataset).length`