# remove img link if not target=blank

Tags: jquery, href, target

I have images on my website, some have the target="_blank" attribute and some not.

here are 2 examples :

with target=_blank :

```
<a href="/mission.jpg" target="_blank"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-1270" src="/mission-300x289.jpg" alt="mission" width="300" height="289" /></a>
```

without target=_blank :

```
<a href="/mission_1.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-1271" src="/mission-300x289.jpg" alt="mission_1" width="300" height="289" /></a>
```

I'm using this code to remove the links from my images :

```
$("a:has(img)").each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).children()); })
```

no I would like to add a condition to remove the link only if the image has not target=_blank attribute.

can anybody helpe me with this ?

thanks a lot for your help;

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("a:not([target='_blank']) img").unwrap();
```

OR

```
$("a[target !='_blank'] img").unwrap();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mphf0qn7/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
     $('a:not([target="_blank"]):has(img)').each(function() { 
         $(this).replaceWith($(this).children()); 
    })
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6xma5tu/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("a:has(img)").each(function() { 
    var x=$(this).attr('target');

    if(x!="_blank"){
      //do your stuff here
    $(this).remove();
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).children()); 
    }
})
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/Leb5f3a6/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("a[target!='_blank']:has(img)").each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).children());
})
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mncpos84/).

Answer (score 0):

This is another way, specifically to check against multiple browsers in relation to this question.

[jQuery hasAttr checking to see if there is an attribute on an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element)

```
$('a:has(img)').each(function() {
    if (!!$(this).attr('target')) {
        (this).unwrap();
    }
});
```