# How to check if svg has a fill-opacity versus a fill-opacity of 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Suppose I want to check the fill-opacity of a SVG element. I'd do this

```
elem.attr('fill-opacity');
```

This can give me back 0 if the element has no fill-opacity attribute or if the fill-opacity has been set to 0.

How do I distinguish between those two cases?

Comment: Are you sure it gives back 0 if the element has no fill-opacity attribute? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element) leads me to believe it would return either `undefined` or `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you simply use elem.hasAttribute?

Comment: It's just rhetorical.

Answer (score 1):

If `fill-opacity` is not specified, `attr()` returns `undefined`.

```js
alert("fill-opacity (DOM) ="+document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("fill-opacity"));
alert("fill-opacity (jQuery) ="+$("#test").attr("fill-opacity"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect id="test" width="10" height="10"/>
</svg>
```