# How to use jQuery to check for alt attribute

Tags: jquery, html

```
<img src="_images/hockey.png" />    
<img src="_images/himalaya.png" alt="Himalaya Picture"/>
```

I have the two pictures above in an html File and I want to check if it has an alt attribute or not.

This is my first day learning JQUERY so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery+check+attribute+exists

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery hasAttr checking to see if there is an attribute on an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on *where you are* and what you want to do. Here are a few pointers:

- `$('img[alt]')` is how in jQuery you select all images with `alt` attribute. And having selected only those elements you're interested in you can call any one of the jQuery methods that achieves your goal. For instance, *add a class to those images*: `$('img[alt]').addClass('myclass')`.
- `$('img')` is how you select all images. You can call a method such as `.each()` on this to iterate through each image using the `this` keyword, then you can check for `alt` attribute/property on each and perform some action if found. Example:

-

```
$('img').each(function() {
    if( this.alt ) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

```js
$('img[alt]').addClass('myclass');
$('img').each(function() {
    console.log( this.alt ? 'HAS ALT' : 'DOES NOT HAVE ALT' );
});
```

```css
.myclass {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="_images/hockey.png" />    
<img src="_images/himalaya.png" alt="Himalaya Picture"/>
```

This would be a great read for you: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info

Answer (score 0):

You could select all img elements and filter by "alt" attribute.

```
$("img[alt]").each(function(){
   console.log($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0qypgs1r/1/

```
     <img src="_images/hockey.png" />    
        <img src="_images/himalaya.png" alt="Himalaya Picture"/>

  <script> 
        $("img").each(function()
    {
        if($(this).prop("alt"))
            alert($(this).prop("alt"));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all images and check for the alt attribute like this

```
$('img').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).prop('alt')) {
        console.log($(this).prop('alt') + ' on element ' + i);
    } else {
        //code for when it has no alt
    }
});
```

In here the `i` thats given as a variable in the function can be used to select the img from `$('img').toArray()`. As it is the position of the image on the page (this starts at `0`).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kezgsgby/