# How to check if a select option have the attribute "value"?

Tags: jquery

I have a `select` like this:

```
<select id="select-filter-item" data-hasqtip="3" oldtitle="Seleziona un tipo di servizio e filtra gli appuntamenti visualizzati sul calendario." title="" aria-describedby="qtip-3">
    <optgroup label="Servizi" type="services-group">
        <option type="provider">Tutti i trattamenti</option>
        <option value="5CFCA63F-5550-4F18-9C03-FC5B50FC67CC" type="service">Taglio capelli </option>
        <option value="B626AD6A-E59B-4D7A-875B-CE3389B11E69" type="service">Colore capelli</option>
        <option value="93003E75-A757-43F0-B2E8-C5ACDD57DBB3" type="service">Trattamenti viso</option>
        <option value="3E9924C3-6AEB-4450-B534-C06DC30F9E35" type="service">Massaggi corpo</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I need to determine if the selected option has the attribute `value`. For example, the first option "*Tutti i trattamenti*" doesn't have any value attribute. How can I implement this in jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use the [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) on the selected option:

```
$("#select-filter-item").find(":selected").is("[value]")
```

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejja0vqt/)**

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 $("#select-filter-item").change(function() {
  var txt = $("#select-filter-item").find(":selected").is("[value]")

   if (txt) {
    alert("has a value")
  } else {
   alert("does not have a value")
  }
});
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7sm9xh31/3/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
$("#select-filter-item").on("change",function(){
    if ($('#select-filter-item option:selected').attr('value') != undefined) {
        console.log("the selected option have the attribute value.")
    }else {
        console.log("the selected option doesn't have any value.")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is by using pure javascript `.hasAttribute()` native function

[**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/t5p9d2kv/) - *check the console*.

```js
var opts = $('#select-filter-item option');

opts.each(function(i) {
  if (!opts[i].hasAttribute("value")) {
    console.log('option-' + i + ': "' + opts[i].innerHTML + '" has no "value" attribute');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-filter-item" data-hasqtip="3" oldtitle="Seleziona un tipo di servizio e filtra gli appuntamenti visualizzati sul calendario." title="" aria-describedby="qtip-3">
  <optgroup label="Servizi" type="services-group">
    <option type="provider">Tutti i trattamenti</option>
    <option value="5CFCA63F-5550-4F18-9C03-FC5B50FC67CC" type="service">Taglio capelli</option>
    <option value="B626AD6A-E59B-4D7A-875B-CE3389B11E69" type="service">Colore capelli</option>
    <option value="93003E75-A757-43F0-B2E8-C5ACDD57DBB3" type="service">Trattamenti viso</option>
    <option value="3E9924C3-6AEB-4450-B534-C06DC30F9E35" type="service">Massaggi corpo</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

---

Same as above but with vanilla javascript [**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/t5p9d2kv/1/)

```
var opts = document.querySelectorAll('#select-filter-item option');

for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
  if (!opts[i].hasAttribute("value")) {
    console.log('option-' + i + ': "' + opts[i].innerHTML + '" has no "value" attribute');
  }
}
```

**Resource:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_hasattribute.asp

Answer (score 0):

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/apnrttds/5/)**

You can do it this way also

```
if($("#select-filter-item").find(":selected").attr("value")!=null){
    alert("VALUE IS THERE");
}
else
{
    alert("VALUE IS NOT THERE");
}
```