# How to check for attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please advise me if I am using correct syntax here for checking if “aria-expanded” is true for a particular set of elements with css class “classname”:

```
    if ($(‘.classname’).hasAttribute('aria-expanded','true')) {  output here }
```

Comment: you want to check whether it's true for _all_ of that set ?

Comment: It his jQuery? Because if it is, then it's incorrect. jQuery doesn't have such as method: https://api.jquery.com/?s=hasAttribute .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery hasAttr checking to see if there is an attribute on an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element)

Comment: are you sure 'aria-expanded' is an attribute? maybe it's another class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have a `hasAttribute` method, so I'm assuming `$ = docuument.querySelector`. (Note: not `document.querySelectorAll`; so, you're only considering a single element).

The `hasAttribute` method takes a single parameter: the name of the attribute you are checking for. To check that attribute's value, you'll need to use `getAttribute` and then compare that. So you might do:

```
if( $('.classname').getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true') {}
```

If you are using jQuery, then you can just use the `attr` method:

```
if ($('.classname').attr('aria-expanded') === 'true') {}
```

See also the [MDN docs for `hasAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute).

If you're trying to check a set of elements, you could do something like this:

```
function allHaveAttribute(elements, attrName, attrValue) {
    // First, check that all elements have the attribute
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (!elements[i].hasAttribute(attrName)) return false;
    }

    if (attrValue) { // if we're checking their value...
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].getAttribute(attrName) !== attrValue)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    } else { // we know all elements have the attribute
        return true;
    }
}

var els = document.querySelectorAll('.classname');

if (allHaveAttribute(els, 'aria-expanded', 'true') {
    // action here
}
```

JSBin Example: http://jsbin.com/payaqijeqa/edit?js,console

Comment: thanks for your reply @andrewburgess, I used your suggestion as following but still not working, can you please have a look again: if( $(‘.classname’).getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true') {     //ouput here }

Following is the element I am applying it on click.

<button aria-expanded="false" type="button" class=“classname” data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                </button>

Comment: @nav What is `$` in your application?

Comment: Its the js syntax, not sure if I get what you're asking

Comment: $(‘.classname’).find('button.classname’).on('click', function () {     if( $(‘.classname’).getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true') {         //ouput     } });

Comment: @nav JavaScript does not have anything assigned to `$` by default. Usually, jQuery is assigned to `$`. If you're not using jQuery, try switching it to `if (document.querySelector('.classname').getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 
"true") { }` If you are using jQuery, you need to "unwrap" the element: `$('.classname').get(0).getAttribute('aria-expanded') === "true"` Or, just use `attr` to get the value `$('.classname').attr('aria-expanded') === "true"`

Comment: $('.classname').attr('aria-expanded') === "true" worked perfectly, Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

1. jQuery doesn't have a `.hasAttribute` function
2. If it did, it would most likely only work on the first of the set

The following uses native JavaScript (ES5) to check that `.every` element in the set `document.querySelectorAll('.classname')` has that attribute set to `true`.

```
let allSet = [].every.call(document.querySelectorAll('.classname'), function(el) {
    return el.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true';
});
```

NB: the above test is case sensitive.  It also ignore any elements that don't have that attribute at all.  If the latter is an issue:

```
let allSet = [].every.call(document.querySelectorAll('.classname'), function(el) {
    return el.hasAttribute('aria-expanded') && el.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if every element with class "className" has the attribute "aria-expanded='true'" with:

```
if( $(".className").length === $(".className").filter("[aria-expanded='true']").length) {
     //output here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS has attribute selectors that allow selection of elements with certain attributes. If you negate the selector (which is unique to jQuery), you can test if there are any elements that have the class but don't have the attribute value by using:

```
$(".className[aria-expanded!='true']").length == 0
```