# How to change <summary> text if <details> has 'open' attr

Tags: jquery, html

If the `details` tag has an `open` attribute, the `summary` text will say "Close".

My attempt at changing the text:

```js
if (jQuery("details").click().attr("open")) {
  jQuery("summary").text("Close");
} else if (jQuery("details").click().attr("")) {
  jQuery("summary").text("Show")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details class="description" open>
  <summary class="">Show</summary>
  <p class="">Description text</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Do you HAVE to use attribute? why not use data attribute with true and false? data-open="true" and read it's value like this: data('open'); and write like this: data('open', true);  If you MUST use attribute... then look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element

Comment: No need for Javascript at all here. This can be achieved with CSS and is aeons faster. See my answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply use CSS for this, here combined with a neat fading/grow/shrink effect:

```css
details.description summary::after {
  content: attr(data-open);
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 5px;
}

details.description[open] summary::after {
  content: attr(data-open);
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
}

details.description summary::before {
  content: attr(data-close);
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 5px;
}

details.description:not([open]) summary::before {
  content: attr(data-close);
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
}

details.description summary::after,
details.description summary::before {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<details class="description" open>
  <summary data-open="Close" data-close="Show"></summary>
  <p>Description text</p>
</details>
```

Here's the minimal version:

```css
details.description[open] summary::after {
  content: attr(data-open);
}

details.description:not([open]) summary::after {
  content: attr(data-close);
}
```

```html
<details class="description" open>
  <summary data-open="Close" data-close="Show"></summary>
  <p>Description text</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Perfect. This saves me in figuring out how to target the element that's being clicked. Did not know about this. Thanks.

Comment: With only CSS you can even make it so the current text fades out and the other fades in. See updated answer.

Comment: Any links that would go in depth about that functionality?

Comment: Nope. It's all in my head, I guess. Maybe someone else can come up with a link?

Answer (score 3):

Use **hasAttribute()** to check if the attribute is existing or not.

```js
$("summary").html("Close");

$("details").click(function() {
  if ($(this)[0].hasAttribute("open")) {
    $("summary").html("Show");
  } else {
    $("summary").html("Close");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details class="description" open>
  <summary class=""></summary>
  <p class="">Description text</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Thank you. By chance if I had 5 or 10 detail/summaries, would I be able to only affect the one that has been clicked?

Comment: Again, simply use CSS for that instead of jQuery or Javascript. CSS also does not have this problem.

Comment: OP put jquery as a tag so I gave him an answer in jQuery. @connexo

Comment: @Paolo That's perfectly fine! I just wanted to point out the superior solution for this special usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimalist solution **without using CSS**.

Simply add or remove the "open" attribute using [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

```js
$("summary").click(function() {
  if($("details")[0].hasAttribute("open")) {
    $("summary").html("See details");
    $("details")[0].removeAttr("open");
  } else {
    $("summary").html("Hide details");
    $("details")[0].attr("open");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <details>
    <summary>See details</summary>
    <p>My details</p>
  </details>
</div>
```