# Check if all required fields are filled in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, required

I have some form fields that are dynamically generated form the database. There are inputs, checkboxes, radio buttons, textarea's, and select's. All the fields are in a parent div with ID `dynamic-form-fields`. Some fields have a `required` attribute.

This is a multi-step form so each "step/page" needs to be validated before going on to the next step. So it's not submitting the form.

How can I check if all the required fields in div `dynamic-form-fields` are filled?

Here's something what my HTML code looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="dff[]" placeholder="Name" required>
<input type="text" name="dff[]" placeholder="Date of Birth">
<input type="text" name="dff[]" placeholder="Email" required>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required>
<select name="pet">
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<button id="check">Check</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById("check").onclick = function () {
        if() {
            alert('error please fill all fields!');
        }
    };
</script>
```

As you see, some fields are required and some are not. It is different every time so the solution has to be dynamic. There are also different types of input's such as select, radio, checkbox, text, etc... How can I make sure every "**required**" field inside the div ID `dynamic-form-fields` is filled?

---

**What i've tried:**

Maybe something like this but how do I get every type of input (text, radio, checkbox, select, etc...) under the div ID `dynamic-form-fields`?

```
$('#dynamic-form-fields input:required').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === '')
      alert('error please fill all fields!');
});
```

Comment: You're adding these in div or is it coming wrapped with div from database ?

Comment: @CodeManiac Hi i saw your answer, I updated the question. It's a multi-step form so your previous wouldn't work since i'm not actually submitting the form. It's a `foreach` loop inside the div `dynamic-form-fields`.

Comment: Why not simply `<form validate>`?

Comment: if it's a multi-step form what you should actually do is check for values only upto a step instead of all the values, and while submitting you should check all the values,

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("check").onclick = function() {
  let allAreFilled = true;
  document.getElementById("myForm").querySelectorAll("[required]").forEach(function(i) {
    if (!allAreFilled) return;
    if (i.type === "radio") {
      let radioValueCheck = false;
document.getElementById("myForm").querySelectorAll(`[name=${i.name}]`).forEach(function(r) {
        if (r.checked) radioValueCheck = true;
      })
      allAreFilled = radioValueCheck;
      return;
    }
    if (!i.value) { allAreFilled = false;  return; }
  })
  if (!allAreFilled) {
    alert('Fill all the fields');
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="dff[]" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input type="text" name="dff[]" placeholder="Date of Birth">
  <input type="text" name="dff[]" placeholder="Email" required>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required>
  <select name="pet" required>
    <option value="">Select a pet</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="check">Check</button>
```

Comment: But there is a problem, `select` does not work and also `radio` does not work

Comment: I've fixed for select box will work on radio and update here @pixie123 for select you need to have a default unselected one with no value at all to get it to work

Comment: Okay thank you! but the problem is I don't even have `value`. How can i make it work if its like this: `<option selected disabled>Select a pet</option>`

Comment: I've fixed it for radio as well please check. Let me know if any other problem arises

Comment: The radio does not seem like its working: https://jsfiddle.net/n6b1oxrv/ and also `select` with option without value does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/n6b1oxrv/1/

Comment: See this fiddle I think I forgot to update my answer https://jsfiddle.net/02hoa3d7/ I've updated my answer as well sorry for that

Comment: No problem, that works thank you. But what about if select default option is `<option selected disabled>` and is required? See this: https://jsfiddle.net/b9Lfyc6h/ should throw error since `select` needs to be selected.

Comment: Use disabled on select and not on option

Comment: There's a _"Tidy"_ button in the snippet editor. Please use it.

Comment: Done @Andreas thanks for your suggestion I was using vscode for formatting

Comment: Really great answer, Thankx @BlackMamba

Comment: Life saver ty !!

Comment: It also wont work if you place the radios first. You need to change this: "allAreFilled = radioValueCheck;" to this "if (!radioValueCheck ) allAreFilled = false;"

Comment: @coderama fixed can you please have a look, else can you please update the answer yourself I'll review it.

Comment: I ended up writing a much longer function that also supports select tags. But your change seems right for the checkbox scenario. Thanks for the radio bit. Saved me some time!

Answer (score 11):

You can use `:invalid` to do this.

Demo:

```js
$('#check').on("click", function(){
  let valid = true;
  $('[required]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':invalid') || !$(this).val()) valid = false;
  })
  if (!valid) alert("error please fill all fields!");
  else alert('valid');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="dff[]" placeholder="Name" required>
<input type="text" name="dff[]" placeholder="Date of Birth">
<input type="text" name="dff[]" placeholder="Email" required>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required>
<select name="pet" required>
    <option selected disabled>Select a pet</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<button id="check">Check</button>
```

Comment: Can you give a example?

Comment: Editted my answer. Please check.

Comment: Upvoted. Checking for ":invalid" attribute is simple and great solution. I used ":valid" attribute instead. For email validation, I defined the input type="email" and let browser validate if the entered value is email or not. Later, used this in form validation
`validForm = $("#email").is(':valid');`

Answer (score 2):

You could keep separate checks based on input type, consider the following:

```js
var isEmpty = false;
$("#check").on('click', function() {
  isEmpty = false
  $('input[type=text]:required').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '')
      isEmpty = true;
  });
  var radioSelected = false;
  //$('input[name=gender]:required').each(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]:required').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      radioSelected = true;
  });

  if (!radioSelected)
    isEmpty = true;

  if ($("[name=pet]").val() == "")
    isEmpty = true;

  //if (!$(".cb").is(":checked"))
  //  isEmpty = true;

  if (isEmpty)
    alert('error please fill all fields!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="dff[]" placeholder="Name" required>
<input type="text" name="dff[]" placeholder="Date of Birth">
<input type="text" name="dff[]" placeholder="Email" required>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required>
<select name="pet" required>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>
<!--<input type="checkbox" class="cb" required />-->
<button id="check">Check</button>
```

Comment: @pixie123 glad it helped

Comment: sorry but `select` and `checkbox` does not work when added and required

Answer (score 1):

You can check is `required` attribute available or not as,

```
$('#dynamic-form-fields').each(function() {
    var hasRequired = $(this).attr('required');
    if (typeof hasRequired !== "undefined" && hasRequired !== false) {
        // This is required inputs.
    }
}
```

Ref : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element)