# If input box is empty show label, if there is text, hide label

Tags: jquery

Is there a way that I can show a `<label>` if a contact form input box is empty and then hide it once someone starts entering text?

This is a sample of my markup

```
<label for="name">Name *</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""/>
```

Comment: I think you are looking for Placeholder. http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/advanced/html5forms2/

Comment: placeholders should do good for your requirement ,but doesnt work in IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#name").bind("keyup", function(e) {
    $('label[for="name"]').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 4):

yes there is,

use `keyup()` function..

```
  $('#name').keyup(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
         $(this).prev().show();
      }else{
         $(this).prev().hide();
      }
 });
```

this is considering your label is always the previous element of textbox

else you can use..

```
   $('#name').keyup(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ''){  
       $('label[for="name"]').show();
       }else{
         $('label[for="name"]').hide();
      }
  });
```

this gets that particular label whose attribute for is name.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to use the attribute "placeholder" for your input field.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name *"/>
```

Otherwise this would help you:

```
$('#name').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val() == '')
    $(this).prev().show();
  else 
    $(this).prev().hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#name").blur(function(){
if($(this).val() == '')
    $("label").attr("style", "visibility: hidden")
else
    $("label").attr("style", "visibility: ")
});
```