# Jquery select all elements that have an accesskey defined

Tags: jquery, .net, access-keys

I want to select all elements that have an accesskey defined on them.

I know that i can do this: `$('[accesskey]')`, but that gives me lot of inputs, hrefs etc, on the page (most of them have an empty accesskey).

What is the way to select only the elements where the accesskey actually has a value?

<sub>Edit: I found the cause of the empty accesskeys as well, was caused by some old disable / restore accesskeys javascript functions over multiple modal dialogs.. normally you won't get that much elements with empty accesskeys</sub>

Comment: You can check this post...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097522/check-existence-of-an-attribute-with-jquery

Comment: @Subhajit: that post is about the existance of an attribute. My question is about an attribute that should have a value, not just the existance of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one selector:

```
$('[accesskey][accesskey!=""]').foo
```

How does it work:

```
// Has the accesskey attribute defined.
[accesskey]

// Doesn't have an empty value for the accesskey attribute.
[accesskey!=""]
```

**Together** it select every element which has the `accesskey` attributes and it's not empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
$('[accesskey]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).prop('accessKey');
});
```

[`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) or like other have already said you can use the [`attribute-not-equal-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/jFZyZ/14/)**

Comment: @thecodeparadox, Thanks. `attr` is fixing that. I thought `attr` and `prop` is interchangeable. Can you please correct me?

Comment: @thecodeparadox. By the way, the problem was with your fiddle, `prop` works just fine... Please don't tell people they are "totally wrong" specially when they are not. :( And joy, you do need to change `accesskey` to `accessKey` if you're using `prop`, properties are case sensitive while attributes are not. Good luck for you both...

Answer (score 0):

you can use and additional loop

```
$("[accesskey]").each(function() {
    if($(this)).attr('accesskey').length > 0) {
        // do it
    }
}
```

i hope it will help you