# Clear Enabled textboxes in form using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, reset

I need to clear/reset the textbox value when it is set to read only = true or Enabled = false . I used reset function in my code but this doesnt work .
My code as

```
function resetForm($form) {
    $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select').val('');   
    $("input[type='hidden']", this).each(function () {
        this.value = '';
    });    
    $form.find('input:checkbox')
         .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');

}

 <asp:TextBox ID="txteventid" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"/>
```

Any suggestions ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your reset function is doing because I cannot see the `if condition` for the `read only` check, but you could try this: < given from your code: > `:)`

i.e. use API ; `.prop` http://api.jquery.com/prop/ and check what is the state of the property or attribute:

rest hope this help for your purpose `:)`

if you keen: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

**and** this might come handy: [Select elements by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097522/check-existence-of-an-attribute-with-jquery)

```
  function resetForm($form) {
    $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select').val('');   
    $("input[type='hidden']", this).each(function () {
        if($(this).prop('readonly')){ // you could check with string i.e. $(this).prop('readonly') === "true"
         this.value = '';
        }
    });    
    $form.find('input:checkbox')
         .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');

}

 <asp:TextBox ID="txteventid" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"/>
```

Comment: no, its not working, can you tell this.prop('readonly') specifies the textbox ??

Comment: hey @kk1076 can you flick a demo; finding bit hard as to what is not working, `:)` **or** put an alert for this `alert($('#txteventid').prop('ReadOnly'));` lemme know what do you get in return, we will sort it out not to worry

Comment: fine. As you mentioned above, the alert appears as undefined. i tried as dis                                                      if $('MainContent_uscEventParameters_txteventid').prop('ReadOnly')) {    document.getElementById("'MainContent_uscEventParameters_txtevent").value = "";
} but its not clearing the value.

Comment: @kk1076 cool so it do not register your element whic you mentioned above, can you please make a demo / jsfiddle I can help you out better if you can replicate it in demo, cheers `:)`