# jQuery click event

Tags: jquery

I want to do following:
Have an  tag inside an  tag. listen to click() event of a tag. in click-event i want to check if img tag has an specific attribute or not.

for example:

```
<a href='#' id='myid'><img src='' alt='' played='1'></a>


$('#myid').click(function(e){
  if(e.target.attr('played')){
    // do something...
  }
});
```

how can i get the attribute of my img tag? i never check the element-handlers in jquery...

kind regards!

Comment: I don't think "played" is a valid attribute for img tag...

Comment: Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097522/check-existence-of-an-attribute-with-jquery

Comment: yeah i found that thread, but it didnt match my needs.

andrea, what else do you suggest if you need to store data to an element? i know this is not the best solution but i didnt found any better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myid').click(function(e){
  if( $(this).find('img').attr('played') == 1)
  {
    // do something...
  }
});
```

ps

better use 'data-played' as the attribute name

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('#myid').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // stopping default behaviour of the anchor
  var played_attribute = $(this).find(img).attr('played');
  if(played_attribute == '1') {
   //attribute had value of 1
  } else {
   //attribute either never existed or didnt have value of 1
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing `$(e.target).attr("played")`