# Show/hide depending on attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with many panels on it, each one shown as a thumbnail. The data for the thumbnails is extracted from a database, so basically the code is as follows:

```
while ($courant = $sth->fetch()) {
    echo '<div class="panel panel-default inline" big=".$courant->big.">
            <div class=panel-body>
              <a class="box" href="something"><img src="some other thing"/>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>';
}
```

The `big` attribute in the main div is either 0 or 1. How can I show/hide div blocks that have `big=0` on a checkbox toggle with JavaScript/jQuery? I know there's a `hide()` function but I think it only works on classes and ids.

Comment: Avoid making up your own attributes. Instead, use the custom data attribute `data-`. For example, `data-big="0"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select elements by attribute with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097522/select-elements-by-attribute-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('[big="0"]').hide();
```