# Jquery check if div has data attribute and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

How can I check if a div has a data-attribute and remove the div if it has that data-attribute, the opposite works like this:

```
$("div[id='foo']").not('[data-type=edit]').remove();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select elements by attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097522/select-elements-by-attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `not()` and use the attribute in the main selector:

```
$('#foo[data-type=edit]').remove();
```

If you only want to find the element that has the `data-type` attribute, regardless of its value, you can use this:

```
$('#foo[data-type]').remove();
```

Comment: This might be wrong because he is asking about `data-type` is present or not. That means `data-type` might have any value. Your code only works only if `data-type=edit` .

Comment: @RanaGhosh true, I took the OP to mean 'that data attribute' as including the value. I'll update to cover both scenarios. Thanks

Comment: How would the Syntax look like if I do this `$("div[id='foo']").`

Comment: That syntax is pretty redundant. The only reason you'd need to use it is if you have multiple elements with the same `id`, which you really, really shouldn't. To answer your question though, you can use multiple attribute selectors like this: `$('div[id="foo"][data-type]')`

Comment: I think that will be `$("div#foo[data-type]")`this .

Comment: ok Thanks alot have a nice day and a nice Weekend :D (Ill accept in a few minutes)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof $("#foo").attr('data-type') == 'undefined')
{
  $("#foo").removeAttr('data-type');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about the value you can just do

```
$('#foo[data-type]').remove();
```