# Get element with attribute from list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a list of multiple elements like you can find in the example snippet below and I'd like to get all elements with a specific attribute `("test"=true)`.

```js
$(function() {
  let elements = $(".myClass") // This property can no be changed so all I got is a variable that includes the callback of multiple jQuery elements.
 
    
  // How to extract all elements with the "test"-attribute from the elements property without using a each function?  
  console.log(elements)
  $(elements).each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("test") === "true")
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="myClass">A</div>
<div class="myClass">B</div>
<div class="myClass" test=true>C</div>
```

Is there any `method` that extracts just elements with specific properties like an attribute named test? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `test` is not a native attribute.  You should make it a data attribute and use it accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select elements by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097522/select-elements-by-attribute)

Comment: Deleted my answer in favor of the duplicate.

Comment: Why do you wrap a jQuery object in a new jQuery object? Also, `elements` is not a property, and it *can* be changed. Use `const` if you want to prevent change.

Comment: `$('.myClass[test]')` (or just `$('[test]')` if the class name isn't relevant)

Comment: @Taplar Even if the dupe holds how to use the attribute selector, the asked question have a given result set, which those answer will not be useful for, so _undelete_ it.

Comment: @LGSon alright, done

Comment: @BramVanroy I‘m pretty sure you‘ve mixed something up. Please read the question content another time.

Comment: @jonas00  Bram is correct that doing `$(elements)` is redundant, as elements is already a jQuery object.

Comment: This is not the question- @Taplar. He did not really understand my comments in the snippet. Because he is Talking about „... it can be changed “ while I‘ve tried to make you know it can not be changed in my case because I don‘t want it to be changed. I‘m pretty sure another look would fix this issue for him :)

Comment: The point of the redundancy is not as a stand alone answer to your question.  It is a simple aside to point out something you are doing that is not necessary.  I'm not saying anything else he said is accurate or not.  I'm simply asserting the truth to the redundancy point.  @jonas00

Comment: As @Taplar points out, my point still stands. SO is for making you a better programmer and comments are here for providing input. I just pointed out the redundancy in your code. I did misinterpret what you meant with *can no be changed*, but that was due to your choice of words I think. As I said, it is not a property. Furthermore, it *can* be changed (unlike `const`s), you just can't (for reasons of your own). Seems like a stupid thing to argue about but when talking about what elements can and cannot do it is better to be clear about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter off of the elements you found.

```js
$(function() {
  let elements = $(".myClass")
  
  console.log( elements.filter('[test="true"]').get() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="myClass">A</div>
<div class="myClass">B</div>
<div class="myClass" test=true>C</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `data` attr (valid HTML) and then select it with jQuery like you are doing, something like:

```
<div data-test='true' class='element1'></div>
<div class='element2'></div>

$(elements).each(function() {
  console.log($(this).data("test") === "true"));
})
```

Edit: As points LGSon `.without using a each function`

> // How to extract all elements with the "test"-attribute from the
>   elements property without using a each function?

In this case:

**Edit 2** (`my mistake`): 
`allTestElements = $(elements).find(`[data-test='true']`);`  //this way you search in elements var instead in all DOM again

And then you have all the elements in the var...

Hope it helps!

Comment: OP wrote _"...without using a each function"_

Comment: Again, OP asks how to get them from a given list, in this case the variable `elements`, with your sample you create them all over again